# Nginx Php5-fpm configuration not working on Maverisks

Tags: mysql, nginx, php

I'm facing with a problem with nginx which took me a whole day. I tried many solutions found on the internet but no success. 
I installed nginx, mysql, php-fpm on MAC through homebrew. It's really easy to install. Everything works as expected except one thing. When every I try to get to my website, it return 404.

Here are the logs, the nginx configuration, the file system structure & privileges.

```
server {
charset utf-8;
client_max_body_size 128M;

listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
#listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

server_name emarketing.com www.emarketing.com;
root        /Users/summernguyen/Documents/workspace/e-marketing/web;
index       index.php;

access_log  /Users/summernguyen/Documents/workspace/e-marketing/runtime/logs/access.log;
error_log   /Users/summernguyen/Documents/workspace/e-marketing/runtime/logs/error.log debug;

location / {
    # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
#error_page 404 /404.html;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
    deny all;
}
```

}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsuQt.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKWAQ.png

Anyone has solved this kind of problem ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem before, it is - as the logs already said - a permissions problem. You have to make sure that *every* folder towards the root of your websites have execution permissions.

You can do so by using **chmod +x /path**

Comment: Thanks Tim, but you can see that every folder have the right permission in my pictures.

Comment: I finally found the problem, because I set the root dir in the sub-sub-sub folder of /Users/summernguyen. It seems that not  correct, I change it to /usr/local/var/www and it works perfectly

Comment: I ment all paths towards your root like. /Users after that /Users/summernguyen and so on. But good that you found a solution yourself.